# explicit specialization for overloading operator '<<' (left shift)

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, explicit-specialization

Lets say i have a class, for which i want to overload an operator based on an enum type:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class option : char { normal, do_something_stupid };

class foo
{
public:

    int i;    
    explicit foo(int a=0) : i(a) {};
    /* overload operator '+=' based on 'option' */
    template<option E = option::normal>
    void operator+=(const foo& f) { i += f.i; }
};

/* explicit specialization for operator += */
template<> void foo::operator+=<option::do_something_stupid>(const foo& f)
{ i += (f.i +1000); }

int main()
{
    foo f1(1), f2(2);
    f1 += f2;
    std::cout << "\nf1 = " << f1.i;
    f1.operator+=<option::do_something_stupid>(f2);
    std::cout << "\nf1 = " << f1.i;

    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This builds clean (ignoring the fact that it really does something pretty dump) both on g++ and clang++.

What if i want to overload the '<<' operator the same way? A similar approach does not seem to work:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

enum class option : char { normal, do_something_stupid };

class foo
{
public:

    int i;

    explicit foo(int a=0) : i(a) {};

    template<option E = option::normal>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const foo& f)
    { o << f.i; return o; }
};

template<> std::ostream&
operator<< <option::do_something_stupid>(std::ostream& o, const foo& f)
{ 
    o << f.i + 1000;
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    foo f1(1), f2(2);

    std::cout << "\nf1= " << f1;
    std::cout << "\nf2= ";
    /* this triggers an error with g++ */
    std::cout.operator<< <option::do_something_stupid>(f1);

    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

According to g++, the call from main to the operator is invalid:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘option’)
std::cout.operator<< <option::do_something_stupid>(f1);
```

clang++ on the other hand, produces a different error message:

```
lsfov.cc:20:1: error: 'operator<<' cannot be the name of a variable or data member
operator<< <option::do_something_stupid>(std::ostream& o, const foo& f)
^
lsfov.cc:20:11: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
operator<< <option::do_something_stupid>(std::ostream& o, const foo& f)
          ^
          ;
lsfov.cc:20:12: error: expected unqualified-id
operator<< <option::do_something_stupid>(std::ostream& o, const foo& f)
           ^
lsfov.cc:33:15: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
    std::cout.operator<< <option::do_something_stupid>(f1);
    ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

which goes on listing possible overload of '<<' from the standard library (if i understand correctly), like:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/ostream:108:7: note: possible target for call
      operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/ostream:117:7: note: possible target for call
      operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      ^
```

What is going on? Is this kind of operator specialization possible/allowed? If so, what is the proper way to call the operator? Or is clang correct and the definition is ill formed?

Comment: A note on the g++ error: the code is invalid. You are attempting to call the member operator that does not exist. Change the code to call the global specialised `operator <<` as such `::operator<< <option::do_something_stupid>(std::cout, f1);` I'm not sure on the "correctness" of the code, having template operators in non-deduced contexts is murky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think clang doesn't like the declaration of the `friend` in relation to the specialisation. Re-ordering them does the trick.

```
enum class option : char { normal, do_something_stupid };

// forward declare the class and operator
class foo;

template<option E = option::normal>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const foo& f);

// the class with the declared friend operator
class foo
{
private:
    int i;
public:
    explicit foo(int a=0) : i(a) {};
    template<option E>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const foo& f);
};

// the operator implementations
template<option E>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const foo& f)
{ o << f.i; return o; }

template<> std::ostream&
operator<< <option::do_something_stupid>(std::ostream& o, const foo& f)
{ 
    o << f.i + 1000;
    return o;
}
```

In addition, the `operator<<` used in the `main` is not a member `cout`, but rather a global.

```
int main()
{
    foo f1(1), f2(2);

    std::cout << "\nf1= " << f1;
    std::cout << "\nf2= ";
    /* this triggers an error with g++ */
    operator<< <option::do_something_stupid>(std::cout, f1);

    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[Sample here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b0ee4c33559278a). g++ is also happy with the code as above.

---

A note on operators in a non-deduced context. I assume you are using the code here in a greater project of some sort, but if the operator is being used with non-deduced parameters, it is often easier and clearer to implement the functionality in a member method or a free function (using `friend` as required).

Comment: Yeap! works like a charm, thanks. `I think clang doesn't like the declaration of the friend in relation to the specialisation.` any clue if there is something wrong with such a statement (syntax), to justify clangs++ behavior? Could it be a bug?

Comment: I think clang is correct here. The name lookup rules are subtle in this case, but the main point is that the overloaded operator must be "visible" outside the class definition in order to find the specialisation. If the first declaration is only in the class, then the operator is considered during name lookup (ADL), but is otherwise not visible, so when the compiler sees the specialisation, it doesn't know what the primary template is, hence the error.